# How to create a systemd service template in NixOS?

Tags: nix, nixos

I tried creating a trivial template service:

```hs
systemd.services."myuser@" = {
  script = "echo Hi, %u";
};
```

Unfortunately the `%u` template is not expanded:

```
$ sudo systemctl start myuser@foo
$ journalctl --catalog --output=cat --unit myuser@foo
Started myuser@foo.service.
Hi, %u
myuser@foo.service: Succeeded.
```

This is because Nix wraps the template string within a script:

```
$ systemctl status --lines=0 myuser@foo
● myuser@foo.service
     Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/wiq9v9kgj78yd3h4dc1rgx0jgdxizrp4-unit-myuser-.service/myuser@.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
$ systemctl show --property ExecStart myuser@foo.service
ExecStart={ path=/nix/store/d6n5gj0llxi2sqhsb87rz7rl0l2rs4x7-unit-script-myuser_-start/bin/myuser_-start ; argv[]=/nix/store/d6n5gj0llxi2sqhsb87rz7rl0l2rs4x7-unit-script-myuser_-start/bin/myuser_-start ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
$ cat /nix/store/d6n5gj0llxi2sqhsb87rz7rl0l2rs4x7-unit-script-myuser_-start/bin/myuser_-start
#!/nix/store/wv35g5lff84rray15zlzarcqi9fxzz84-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash -e
echo Hi, %u
```

What is the canonical way to create a template service in NixOS? Do I need to override `ExecStart`, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Linking https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/80933, currently NixOS doesn't support systemd template units.

Answer (score 4):

`systemd.services.<name>.script` is only a convenience for otherwise simple services that need a script instead of a command to start. Defining `ExecStart` is perfectly fine.

```hs
systemd.services."myuser@" = {
  serviceConfig.ExecStart = "echo Hi, %u";
};
```

or pass `%u` as an argument:

```hs
systemd.services."myuser@" = {
  serviceConfig.ExecStart = 
    let
      script = pkgs.writeScript "myuser-start" ''
        #!${pkgs.runtimeShell}
        user="$1"
        echo Hi, $user";
      '';
    in "${script} %u";
};
```

> or is there a more elegant solution?

There's no elegance in configuration.

The way I see it, elegance comes from intrinsic simplicity, whereas abstraction comes from hiding complexity.

Configuration is what emerges when software needs to support more use cases than it can elegantly support.
NixOS modules are an effort to both model these configurations and build higher-level modules and options on top of them, forming abstractions that are optional. (Fun fact: your own configuration is also a module and is equally powerful)

If you're looking for something to appreciate, it's the fact that you sometimes get to choose which abstractions you use within NixOS, giving you choice. That's the next best thing after intrinsic simplicity, which is rare in configuration, and better than forced abstraction.